# Converting colors on lines in chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am make some forecast related with caret package.Output from this forecast you can see below

```
data_for.cm_rpart <- data.table(Data = c(final_predictions.rpart$Customs_duties,final_predictions.rpart$Predictions),                      
                                              Date = c( rep(final_predictions.rpart$Date )),
                                              Type = c(#rep("Train data", nrow(data_train)),
                                                rep("Test data", nrow(final_predictions.rpart)),
                                                rep("Forecast", nrow(final_predictions.rpart))))
              
              ggplot(data_for.cm_rpart, aes(Date, Data, color = Type), palette = c("#0073C2FF", "#FC4E07")) +
                geom_line(size = 0.9, alpha = 0.75)
```

[image]

On this chart you can see that last line is red color and this line actually overlap with green color.

But I need to change this and to make some similar chart in colors like chart below:
[image]

So can anybody help me how to change colors and make first chart similar like second ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should set alpha inside `aes` and alter it latter using `scale_alpha_manual` such that the 2 lines have different transparency.

```
# example data
data_for.cm_rpart = data.frame(Date = 2017:2020, 
                               Data = c(1:4, 3:4, 3:4), 
                               Type = c(rep('forecast',4), 
                                        rep('test data', 4)))

# plot
ggplot(data_for.cm_rpart, aes(Date, Data, color = Type, alpha = Type), 
       palette = c("#0073C2FF", "#FC4E07")) +
  geom_line(size = 0.9)+
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.5))
```